# Конструкция «ох(,) как...»

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, междометие

Скажите, пожалуйста, в этом предложении после "ох" нужна запятая или нет?

*Хотя многое давалось **ох как** нелегко.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нет, запятая здесь не нужна.  В устойчивых оборотах  подобного типа запятая не ставится.

Comment: Думаете это устойчивый оборот?
"Ох как" более похоже на усилительную частицу.
Запятой, естественно, не нужно.

Answer (score 1):

В орфографическом словаре:
[ох как... ох какой...](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&ro=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BE%D1%85%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA)

В словаре Ожегова:
[**ОХ**](http://endic.ru/ozhegov/Oh-21656.html)
**2. *Междометие.*** Усиливает слово, к которому примыкает — одно или вместе с местоименными словами “как”, “какой”. *Живётся ему ох как несладко. Надоел ты мне, ох* (ох и, ох как) *надоел.*

Запятая после междометия в таких конструкциях не ставится.
*Да, слава шла впереди Килпатрика, и соответствовать такой репутации **ох как нелегко*** (И. Рэнкин).