# «И ох если я его у тебя не найду!» Пунктуация

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, междометие, частицы

Вот это **ох если** как-то должно выделяться запятыми? В Нацкорпусе только такое нашла:

> ***И ох как*** по прошлым годам он помнил эту мёртвую, пропахшую крезолом скуку! [Ю.О. Домбровский. Факультет ненужных вещей, часть 1 (1978)]
>   *Что правда то правда: хороша **и ох как** желанна была Арина попервоначалу ― чуть блеклая красота, польская кровь, богемные замашки, своя в черт-те каких кругах и уже года два как безуспешно добивается разрешения на выезд из страны.* [Сергей Гандлевский. НРЗБ // «Знамя», 2002]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Так интересно!
На мой взгляд, в этом случае **всё зависит от интонации**. "***Ох***" может быть и междометием, и частицей. Я бы прочитал эту фразу без каких-либо пауз и, соответственно, не поставил бы никаких знаков препинания. Данное предложение очень разговорное, его можно произнести на одном дыхании с ударением на последнем слове: ...***найдУ!***

А в Нацкорпусе можно найти различные варианты, например такой:

*И ― ах, если б некто, смелый сердцем, хватил по публике статьёй о сложности жизни внутренней, жизни души!* [Максим Горький. Письма (1889-1906)]

И ещё, как мне видится, немаловажную роль здесь играет начальное ***И***. Это может быть и частица, и союз — не хватает контекста, предшествующих "вводных". Но без неё (него) очень вероятна запятая-пауза после **ох**, что можно увидеть в многочисленных примерах. А вот с ***И*** в начале я не могу представить эту паузу (хотя... представил... — могу, конечно). Скорее, микропауза будет после всей этой комбинации:

***И ох если // я его у тебя найду!***

Comment: Да, кстати, вариант вообще без знаков мне нравится даже больше, чем с одной только запятой после "ох". Но поиском я ничего подобного не нашёл.

Comment: @grizzly  Тоже рылся, да. Обсуждаемое предложение очень разговорное, может произноситься на одном дыхании... с ударением на последнем слове _найдУ!_

Comment: Мне нравится ваш вариант, Александр. Я читаю и произношу эту фразу с той же интонацией. "Ох" тут вроде как угроза, а не "ох-вздох", и пауза будто портит смысл и настрой.

Comment: @Юлия Да, Юлия, **И ох Если**, по-моему, следует читать "слитно" с небольшим ударением на  "если".

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец Да, согласна! Я не утверждаю, что запятой тут быть не должно по правилам, я в них не сильна :) Но не это ли тогда случай авторской пунктуации, когда отсутствием запятой, я смогу показать интонацию и динамику (если так можно выразиться) разговора?

Comment: @Юлия Почему не по правилам? "Ох" переходит в частицу, и запятая не нужна.

Comment: @АлександрСтрелец, тогда тем более :)

Comment: @Юлия Вот смотрите: _Не являются междометиями и, cледовательно, не отделяются запятыми частицы: **о**, употребляемая при oбращении, **ну, ах, ох** и т. п., употребляемые для выражения усилительного оттенка_. [Грамота.ру](http://new.gramota.ru/biblio/readingroom/rules/155-zap-19-36).

Answer (score 3):

В приведённых примерах после "охов" нигде не начинается придаточное с союзом "если", это просто другие случаи: *ох как он помнил,  ох как желанна была Арина* (а усилительная частица "и" нам совсем не мешает).

“И ох, если я его у тебя не найду!”

> Ох, если только эти несчастные Хранители позволят нам выйти отсюда.
>
> Ох, если я его встречу...
>
> Ох, если честно, то у меня в спине хребет похрустывает.

Comment: Приве-е-т... Я вот думаю, что в восклицательном предложении точно нужна запятая. А в сложном предложении? Например:  И ох если я его у тебя не найду, то тогда смотри у меня. А как  вы думаете?

Comment: Я думаю, что запятая все равно нужна. _Ох, если б не этот огород, не баба крепкой рабочей кости и ее суровые, но дельные родители, пропадать бы пришлось и Феде, и двум его девчонкам, которые как-то сами собой изладились и выскочили на свет белый невесть откудова._ [Виктор Астафьев. Рассказы (2000) // «Новый Мир», 2001]

Comment: Шаронушка, или знаки менять типо отточие после "ох", или будет работать *если...то*, т. е. без запятой. Но ввиду НЕ СМОТРИТСЯ рисуем отточие. И - совсем не поняла про восклицательнось предложения. Не клик, так обратно же отточие (у автора вопроса).

Answer (score 2):

«*В гугло-книгах, как я поняла, зачастую самиздат и авторская пунктуация*».

**Об авторской пунктуации для междометий и междометных выражений**

1) Давайте будем точны и внимательны **в терминологии**, которую мы применяем.
По Розенталю,  **авторская пунктуация** – это  сознательное отступление от действующих норм  и особое применение знаков препинания в художественных текстах, такая пунктуация  не соответствует  правилам, но оправдана стилем, жанром, контекстом — всеми особенностями произведения. Также это особенности пунктуационного оформления текстов, носящие индивидуальный характер.

Но иногда под авторской пунктуацией понимается следующее: **правил не знаю, пишу как мне нравится.**

2) Итак, чтобы определить авторскую пунктуация, **прежде всего надо знать правила**, а они в этой теме формулируются в общем виде, запомнить их **несложно**. И решаются подобные задачи также в общем виде, нет смысла искать отдельное правило для каждого конкретного случая.

**Для справок**

**Междометие** – это часть речи, которая непосредственно выражает чувства и желания, не называя их.   **Частица** – это служебная часть речи, придающая другим словам дополнительный смысловой оттенок. Частицы относятся к различным знаменательным частям речи.

Одни и те же слова в предложении могут иметь значение **междометия или частицы**. Междометия всегда обособляются, в то время как частицы относятся к определённым слова и не обособляются.

В парных вариантах **междометия следует отличать от частиц**.  Междометия произносятся с интонацией обособления, то  есть составляют отдельную фразу с интонационным ударением,  которая выделяется  паузой.  На частицы не падает ударение, и они произносятся без паузы.

**Междометные сочетания**

На основе междометий  образуются междометные сочетания, в которые дополнительно могут входить  различные **союзы  и частицы**.  Такие комплексы также функционируют **или как междометия, или как частицы**. Состав их довольно свободен, словарем не нормируется.  Междометные выражения должны быть осмысленными, употребительными в речи  и **удобными для произношения**.

Поэтому не имеет смысла говорить о том, что **союз КАК** может в них использоваться, а вот **союз ЕСЛИ** нет. Они равноправны в этом случае, но выражения с союзом КАК более частотны, так как односложному союзу легче образовать  устойчивую фонетическую группу.

3) ***И ох если я его у тебя не найду!***

Предложение не кажется мне удачным для разбора и изучения темы. Оно даже выглядит своеобразно – как набор из предлогов, частиц, союзов и местоимений. **И произносится с трудом в любом виде, какая уж тут интонация!**

Сочетание ***и ох если***  также фонетически небезупречно, вот оно-то и представляется неудачно авторским. Плохо туда вписывается союз И, получается такое **«и-ох»**, напоминающее  звуки из животного мира. Контекста нет, как можно работать с таким предложением?

**Рассмотрим что-нибудь попроще.** Например, мать выговаривает подростку-сыну:  *«Ладно, погуляй немного, но чтобы не позже десяти часов был дома. **И ох, если** ты не придешь вовремя!*»

В коротком предложении это сочетание хотя бы произносится.  Интересно, что здесь возможны **оба варианта** (с обособлением и без обособления). Они совпадают по смыслу (обещание неприятностей для непослушного чада) и даже **произносятся практически одинаково**: ударение в обоих случаях падает на ***ох***, только пауза при обособлении чуть длиннее.

Таким образом, всё авторство заключается в том, чтобы построить фразу в соответствием с желанием автора **выразить чувство отдельно или не делать этого.**

4) Но это простейшая бытовая фраза, а в художественных произведениях иногда приходится делать выбор **и по смыслу, и по фонетике**.

Приведу небольшой пример.

***«Ох если бы*** приехал сюда однажды путешественник-книгочей, помнящий чеховское сравнение Листвянки с Ялтой, – как он был бы разочарован!»
Владимир Жемчужников, Байкальская история. Отрывок из книги.

*12 июня 1890 года прибыл Чехов к берегу Байкала; к большой бухте, из коей, как их переполненной каменной чаши, широкой и сильной струей текла Ангара. С переправой вышла задержка и, дожидаясь попутного парохода, он прожил двое суток Листвянке. В письме к родным Антон Павлович делился впечатлениями: «Берега высокие, крутые, каменистые, лесистые; станция Лиственичная расположена у самой воды и поразительно похожа на Ялту; будь дома белые, совсем была бы Ялта...*

И вот в приведенном предложении  ***ох*** – это именно частица, не междометие, она не выделяется отдельно, но относится к союзу ЕСЛИ и, соответственно, **ко всему придаточному предложению**. Выражает опасение: не дай бог кто-то приедет, чтобы насладиться красотой, вот будет разочарован.

Answer (score 1):

В приведенных Вами примерах из Нацкорпуса говорится о сочетании **ох как**, которое от последующего текста не отделяется ([**Конструкция «ох(,) как…»**](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/10751/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BE%D1%85-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA)).

Но здесь другой случай: [ОХ](http://endic.ru/ozhegov/Oh-21656.html) — это междометие; [И](http://russkiy-na-5.ru/articles/294) — усилительная частица. Считаю, что такой симбиоз нуждается выделении запятыми (или другими знаками).
**И ох, если я его у тебя не найду!**

> Ох, если бы это летала над нами смерть на бледном коне! Страшно это, но красиво! Ох, если бы это чудовище носилось над городом (Е. Шварц).
>   Ох... если бы брошенным, опостылевшим, отвергнутым, а может быть, никогда не знавшим любви женщинам не говорили бабушки, что они самые красивые... (Е. Гришковец)

В [Нацкорпусе](http://processing.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?sort=i_grtagging&lang=ru&lex1=%D0%BE%D1%85&env=alpha&startyear=1922&lex2=%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B8&max2=1&text=lexgramm&sem-mod2=sem&sem-mod2=sem2&sem-mod1=sem&sem-mod1=sem2&level1=0&level2=0&endyear=1942&mode=main&parent1=0&min2=1&nodia=1&parent2=0&p=2) достаточно примеров, правда, без "и", но (как выразилась Галина Аванесова) это нам не мешает.

Ох, если выгорит это дельце — тогда посмотрим, какие он номера будет загибать на сенокосе! [Федор Абрамов. Братья и сестры (1958)]
Вот именно, таяла. Ну, я приду ― ох, если застану! Топориком это дело пресеку... [Георгий Владимов. Три минуты молчания (1969)]
Ох, если вдуматься, наше предприятие попахивает безнадежностью… [И. А. Ефремов. Звездные корабли (1944)]

Answer (score 1):

Для ответа на вопрос важно понимать, с какой интонацией произносит это автор. Мне сложно представить такую фразу без паузы после **и**. Но тогда эту паузу необходимо обозначить каким-то знаком препинания. Гугло-книги в подобных случаях находят и многоточие, и тире, и запятую (но вообще без знака мне не попалось ни разу). Думаю, что с наибольшей вероятностью (в условиях неизвестного контекста) лучше всего подойдёт многоточие:

**И... ох, если я его у тебя не найду!**

Comment: В гугло-книгах, как я поняла, зачастую самиздат и авторская пунктуация. Там вообще кто в лес, кто по дрова :) Я задавала тут вопрос про "простиралось" / "простилалось", которые там используются по-разному в одинаковом контексте.